# what is extends is equal to when desugarified, javascript harmony

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-harmony

Assuming I had an ecmascript 5 class

```
function vehicle(){
    this.hasWheels=true;
} 

vehicle.prototype.getWheels=function(){return this.haswheels;};
```

but it was defined using the new ecmascript class syntax, would creating a "car" class that `extends` vehicle use `vehicle.prototype` as a prototype or would it use a new instance of vehicle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> would creating a "car" class that extends vehicle use vehicle.prototype as a prototype or would it use a new instance of vehicle?

Neither. It does not simply extend not the `vehicle.prototype`, and it does not create an instance (`new vehicle`).

Instead, it properly creates a new object that inherits from the vehicle prototype, like

```
Car.prototype = Object.create(Vehicle.prototype);
```

---

However, it actually does more than that. In the [maximally minimal classes](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman%3amaximally_minimal_classes) proposal the `extends`is defined in terms of the [`<|` prototype operator](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:proto_operator) ([archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20160404123540/http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:proto_operator)):

```
class Car extends Vehicle { constructor(){} }
```

is equivalent to

```
const Car = Vehicle <| function Car(){};
```

which in ES5 looks like

```
function Car(){}
Car.__proto__ = Vehicle; // not so much ES5
Car.prototype = Object.create(Vehicle.prototype);
```